# Please anyone can explain this JavaScript code, how is work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters

This is JavaScript code and this works perfectly but the problem is I can't understand how this works. If anyone knows how this works please explain it to me.

This is the query = `?cid=619386618c57a571f4463d45&type=page`

```
export default (query) => {
    if(query){
        const queryString = query.split("?")[1];
        if(queryString.length > 0){
            const params = queryString.split("&");
            const paramObj = {};
            params.forEach(param => {
                const keyValue = param.split("=");
                paramObj[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
            });
            return paramObj;
        }
    }

    return {};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is almost zero React here. It is quite plain JavaScript

```
export default (query) => { // this is the only react here
    if(query){ // if there is a string 
        const queryString = query.split("?")[1]; // get the stuff after the ?
        if(queryString.length > 0){ // if there was stuff after the ? 
            const params = queryString.split("&"); // split on & (gives an array)
            const paramObj = {}; // create an object
            params.forEach(param => { // for each part of the split array 
                const keyValue = param.split("="); // split on the = 
                paramObj[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1]; // use the string before the = as key and after as value 
            });
            return paramObj; // return the object
        }
    }

    return {}; // otherwise return empty object
}
```

The whole thing can be written

```
export default (query) => {
  let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(query);
  const result = {};
  for (const [key, value] of urlParams.entries()) { 
    result[key] = value;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Test:

```js
const getParams = query => {
  let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(query);
  const result = {}
  for (const [key, value] of urlParams.entries()) { // each 'entry' is a [key, value] tupple
    result[key] = value;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getParams("?cid=619386618c57a571f4463d45&type=page"))
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much.